# swift PDFView not show filled pdf form

Tags: ios, forms, pdf, fill

I have a PDF file with fields to fill out. and fill them with this code:

```
PDFDocument *documento = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:dataFile];

for (int index = 0;index<documento.pageCount;index++) {
            PDFPage *page = [documento pageAtIndex:index];
            if (page != nil) {
                NSArray *annotations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:page.annotations];
                for (PDFAnnotation *annotation in annotations ){

                    PDFAnnotation *annTemp = annotation.copy;
                    [annTemp setValue:[dizionarioForm objectForKey:[json objectForKey:annotation.fieldName]] forAnnotationKey:PDFAnnotationKeyWidgetValue];

                    [page removeAnnotation:annotation];
                    [annotation setShouldDisplay:false];
                    page.displaysAnnotations = false;
                    [page addAnnotation:annTemp];


                }
            }
        }

        self.pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        self.pdfView.displayMode = kPDFDisplaySinglePage;
        self.pdfView.autoScales = true;
        self.pdfView.displayDirection = kPDFDisplayDirectionVertical;
        self.pdfView.document = nil;
        self.pdfView.document = documento.copy;
        UIViewController *pdfVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

        [pdfVC.view addSubview:self.pdfView];
        pdfVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(pdfViewAzioni)];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pdfVC animated:true];
```

When it is displayed, however, the fields are white, and the value appears only when I select the field ...
How could I display the value immediately?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the annotation's background color worked for me. The chosen color doesn't seem to matter.